# command line perl: split string to modify first part

Tags: perl, command-line

I have a file that looks like:

```
SNP Al1 Al2 Freq1   MAF AvgCall Rsq Genotyped   LooRsq  EmpR    EmpRsq  Dose1   Dose2
20:60479    C   C   1.00000 0.00000 1.00000 0.00000 -   -   -   -   -   -
20:60522:T_TC   R   R   1.00000 0.00000 1.00000 0.00000 -   -   -   -   -   -
20:60571    C   C   1.00000 0.00000 1.00000 0.00000 -   -   -   -   -   -
20:60795    G   C   0.99627 0.00373 0.99627 0.02668 -   -   -   -   -   -
....
```

I'd like to change the entries that look like

```
20:60522:T_TC    R      R    1.00000
```

into the same format as the rest of the lines, namely

```
20:60522    R   R    1.00000
```

I'm trying to do it the python way by splitting the string, changing the offending part, and then adding it to the line and printing the line. How do I do this?

Here is (one of the many things) I have tried so far:

```
perl -wnl -e '@lines = split $_; print lines[0]' testrun
```

Make array from line, then get the first entry (That is, I have not been able to capture the part I'd like to modify yet.)

Problem is that this returns

```
print() on unopened filehandle lines at -e line 1, <> line 1. etc
```

Ps. I know there are solutions that can change the string with a sed-like pattern, but I was not able to get them to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from missing the `$` when printing `$lines[0]`.

In addition, `split $_` is equivalent to `split $_, $_` which isn't going to give you anything. Instead, allow [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to take the default arguments (equivalent to `split ' ', $_`):

```
perl -wnl -e '@lines = split; print $lines[0]' testrun
```

You could also take advantage of the [`-a` flag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) which will automatically split each line into an array `@F`:

```
perl -wnla -e 'print $F[0]' testrun
```

Then you can manipulate `$F[0]` and print out the new value with the rest of the line:

```
perl -wnla -e '$F[0] =~ s/:\D+$//; print join "\t", @F;' testrun
```

Answer (score 4):

This replaces a colon followed by letters and underscore with a space:

```
perl -wpe 's/:[a-zA-z_]+/ /' testrun
```

Here is my output:

```
SNP Al1 Al2 Freq1   MAF AvgCall Rsq Genotyped   LooRsq  EmpR    EmpRsq  Dose1   Dose2
20:60479    C   C   1.00000 0.00000 1.00000 0.00000 -   -   -   -   -   -
20:60522    R   R   1.00000 0.00000 1.00000 0.00000 -   -   -   -   -   -
20:60571    C   C   1.00000 0.00000 1.00000 0.00000 -   -   -   -   -   -
20:60795    G   C   0.99627 0.00373 0.99627 0.02668 -   -   -   -   -   -
```